# stopping multiple containers gracefully, is the docker stop `--time` option for each container or for all containers?

Tags: bash, docker, containers, containerd, graceful-shutdown

I'm trying to stop all containers gracefully. So I want to give each container 60 seconds. I see that you can do:

```
docker stop --time=60 $(docker container ls -q)
```

#### is the `--time=60` for each container or do all the containers only get 60 seconds?

- for example: if one container takes 59 seconds to stop... does that mean the next container only gets 1 second to stop?
- if all the containers get 60 seconds... then i will do a bash for loop and do docker stop on each container... to ensure they each get 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `--time=60` are considered for each container.

Docker client do HTTP requests for under the hood. When you pass more than one argument like this:

```sh
docker stop --time=60 $(docker container ls -q)
```

Docker client will send as many requests as the values returned by your shubshell `docker container ls -q`, each request will have a `--time` for their own.

Now that we know docker do requests to "docker api", we can look on [API Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerStop) and notice there is no endpoint to stop or kill a lot of containers, only one per call.